# Decidability of intersection of two languages of same type

Tags: formal-languages, computability, automata, undecidability, semi-decidability

Given two context-sensitive languages, $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the problem of "*whether $L_1 \cap L_2$ also belongs to CSL*" decidable?

I have the same question for the case when $L_1$ and $L_2$ belongs to Recursive/Recursively enumerable language. I think, they are decidable because they are closed under intersection operation as can be seen [here.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~mdtpetri/cs360/rerecclose.pdf) But I haven't found any text mentioning this explicitly so I can't be sure.

Comment: All three classes you mention are closed under intersection, so the problems are trivially decidable (i.e. by the algorithm: "return YES"). Are you perhaps searching for proof of closure under intersection?

Comment: I was looking for confirmation that closure under a property implies decidability for that property. I guess that is trivial then. @potestasity